# How to traverse a list starting from a selected point?

Tags: python, list, traversal

How can I traverse a list with a starting point not equals to index 0?

In my specific case, I have have a list with numbers that may or may not be contiguous (for example: 1,2,5,8,11,35,664). And depending on user input, I want to start traversing from a certain point.

Using the same above example, suppose I want to start traversing from 8 onward.

Comment: They're *very* different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
a[a.index(8):]

a = [1,5,8,3,5,7]

>>> print a[a.index(8):]
[8,3,5,7]
```

Comment: Facepalm. Why didn't I think of this?

Comment: You are creating another list and `a.index` throws an exception in the worst case

Comment: @thefourtheye If my list where in the millions of entries, will it cause performance issues?

Comment: @drum Yup, `list.index` has to traverse the list one by one to find the first element and then from that element onwards a new list is created. I believe Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's `dropwhile` is the best suit for this.

Comment: My original problem was to traverse a dictionary because I can fetch the starting point with O(1) but it wasn't iterable without the help of a list. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> for i in itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x != 8, [1, 2, 5, 8, 11, 35, 664]):
...   print i
... 
8
11
35
664
>>> for i in itertools.islice([1, 2, 5, 8, 11, 35, 664], 3, None):
...   print i
... 
8
11
35
664
```

Comment: Why not `list.index`, instead of hardcoding `3`?

Comment: Won't dropwhile() cause performance issues since it still has to iterate over the whole list?

Comment: @drum: Sure, but sometimes it's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

If your user's input is going to be the index value itself you can use:

```
for x in list[index:]
```

to simply go forward from from the index number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want dictionary of `{value:index}`. You can do like this. But it only work when element in the list are all unique.

```
>>> a = [1,2,5,8,11,35,664]
>>> b = dict(zip(a, xrange(len(a))))
>>> print "index of 8 is", b[8]
index of 8 is 3
>>> print "index of 35 is", b[35]
index of 35 is 5
```

Comment: Not what I'm asking for.